# Updating an entity framework 4 model with a many to many relationship, how?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I have a entity model with the following objects:

- House
- Task
- TaskType

I have the following relationships:
House <1>----<*> Task (One to many)
Task <*>----<1> TaskType (Many to one)

Now, I wanted to add a many to many relationship between House and TaskType, to set which TaskTypes are available for a house.

What is the correct way to do this in Visual Studio 2010 without losing data in the database.

If I do this on a brand new model, which doesn't have any database generated yet, it works fine, but if I try to add it after I've generated the database the first time, I will loose all my data since the genereated SQL drops all tables.

If I try to create a table manually in the DB called HouseTaskTypes with two columns (House_Id and TaskType_Id) with foreign keys to House and TaskTypes, it looks weird when I update the model from the database.

I can probably get it to work with some manual adjustments, but I'd like to know what the correct way is of adding a many-to-many association/relationship in an already existing Entity Framework model.

All ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrating an existing database schema to a new one is not supported in EF 4.1. From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696165%28v=vs.103%29.aspx):

> Code First does not support migration
>   of an existing database schema. The
>   Entity Framework 4.1 does support
>   dropping and re-creating a database
>   schema when the model changes through
>   using database initializers. The
>   following initializers are supported:
>   CreateDatabaseIfNotExist,
>   DropCreateDatabaseAlways, and
>   DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges

So, to solve your problem, I would

- set the intializer to CreateDatabaseIfNotExist, or turn it off
- manually add the table to the database
- manually add the navigation properties to your model
- manually map the many-to-many relationship (see below)
- then add any data to the new table either through your app or manually

To manually map the relationship **add the following method to your DBContext**

```
 class protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new HouseConfiguration());   `
 }
```

Then, in the same, or reachable, namespace as your DBContext class, add a configuration class for one side of the many-to-many relationship. The purpose of this class is do the actual mapping. I typically have a separate namespace just for these configuration classes.

```
class HouseConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<House>
{
    public HouseConfiguration()
    {
        // many-to-many w/tasktypes
        this.HasMany(h => h.TaskTypes)
            .WithMany(tt => tt.Houses) 
            .Map(m =>
                {
                    m.ToTable("HouseTaskTypes");
                    m.MapLeftKey("HouseId");
                    m.MapRightKey("TaskTypeId");
                });

    }
}
```

You will have to double check the property names/key names, but this should do it.

Comment: That's what I've been trying to do. I first added a "in-between" table with two columns, one for the House_id and one for TaskType_id. This was done in the SQL Server (2008 R2 Express)

Then I tried adding a many-to-many association between the "House" entity and the "TaskType" entity in the Entity Model designer in Visual Studio. Problem is that I get the error "No mapping specified for the following entityset/associationset".
And since the table does not appear in the "Model Browser -> Store -> Tables / Views" section, I cannot map to it.